# Using DateListPlot without connecting dots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of values like this:

[image]

When I plot this data using `DateListPlot[data]` I get a plot connecting the individual points such as:

[image]

My question are:

1. How can I create the same plot but only getting the individual points without connect them by line?. Similar to the plot below:
2. How can I get the AM or PM from the times and put them in the x-axis?
3. How can I space the time to be every 5 minutes when plotting the data (similar to the picture below)?

[image]

**EDIT:**

The data is the following:

```
{{DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 1, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 
  122.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 6, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  108.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 11, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  99.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 16, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  101.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 21, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  106.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 26, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  110.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 31, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  112.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 36, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  102.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 41, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  96.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 46, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  96.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 51, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  94.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 8, 56, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  92.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 1, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  95.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 6, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  98.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 11, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  93.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 16, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  84.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 21, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  80.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 26, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  78.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 31, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  74.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 36, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  60.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 41, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  54.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 46, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  57.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 51, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 
  59.}, {DateObject[{2020, 7, 5, 9, 56, 0.}, "Instant", 
   "Gregorian", -5.], 68.}}
```

Comment: use the option `Joined -> False`?

Comment: @kglr thank you! I was not aware this simple trick as possible!. Is there something similar like this to put the AM or PM values of the times in the x-axis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Q1.** Use the option `Joined -> False`:

```
DateListPlot[data, Joined -> False]
```

[image]

**Q2.** Use the option [`DateTicksFormat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateTicksFormat.html) *"to put the AM or PM values of the times in the x-axis"*:

```
DateListPlot[data, Joined -> False, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Hour", ":", "Minute", "AMPM"}]
```

[image]

**Q3.** Specify the date ticks using [`DateRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateRange.html) with `{5, "Minute"}` as the increment:

```
dticks = DateRange[##, {5, "Minute"}] & @@ MinMax[data[[All,1]]];

DateListPlot[data, Joined -> False, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"HourShort", ":", "Minute", "\n", "AMPM"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {dticks, Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

To get more control on formatting of date tick labels, you can use a custom labeling function:

```
ClearAll[dateFormat]
dateFormat[d_] := Column[DateString[d, #] & /@ {{"HourShort", ":", "Minute"}, "AMPM"}, 
   Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> 0]

DateListPlot[data, Joined -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
   {{#, dateFormat @ #} & /@ dticks, Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr thank you! This is exactly what I wanted for the first question! I really appreciate. I put a 3 question similar to this as well. I imagine it must be something simple as well.

Comment: @John please see the updated version.

Comment: kglr thank you this is great!. However, the line `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
   Automatic}, {DateRange[#, #2, {5, "Minute"}] &, Automatic}}` does not work. It shows "Transpose: the first two levels of {<<1>>} cannot be transposed". How can I fix that?

Comment: @John, I updated with a variant  that works in version 12.0+.

Comment: kglr thank you very much! I accepted your answer. I appreciate it !